# python-inverse-of-a-matrix failure to import

Tags: python, matrix-inverse

I thought that the code in the python-inverse-of-a-matrix was extremely interesting, particularly since I have used numpy for several years in computations that involve matrices. I was disappointed as the 2 imports from numpy failed.  Here are the imports:

```
from numpy import matrix
from numpy import linalg
```

Neither matrix nor linalg were found in the numpy package. Clearly I miss something that is quite obvious (not for me, though :) ).

I use Linux (kubuntu) and downloaded the numpy package as a debian package. Are there other packages for "matrix" and for "linalg", if so, what are they?

Thank you in anticipation,

OldAl.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely, you have a `numpy.py` or `numpy.pyc` file in your local directory... and python is finding it and importing it instead of the numpy package you expect.

Try this before importing.

```
import numpy
print(numpy.__file__)
```

You'll probably find that `numpy.__file__` is pointing not to the numpy package, but to something you did not intend to import.

In general, it's a good idea to name your own modules with different names from known/popular packages.

Comment: Actually, numpy is imported and works correctly. Has for the last 5 years... The deb package numpy simply does not have the matrix and linalg sub-packages. In ubuntu or kubuntu one needs to import scipy as well.  Scipy expands the name space of numpy and adds matrix and linalg packages and more. 

Thanks for you contribution!

OldAl.

Comment: OldAl - since you found your answer, I suggest you answer you own question, then mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**
The deb package numpy simply does not have the matrix and linalg sub-packages.

In ubuntu or kubuntu one needs to import scipy as well. Scipy expands the name space of numpy and adds matrix and linalg packages.
OldAl.